# how spring-mvc finds the right class to instantiate and fill its data with POST-REQUEST fields

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, data-binding, http-post

first of all,i am fairly new with spring mvc so ..

how springmvc find the right class to instantiate and fill its object properties when sending post-request to some controller.
for example lets assume i have this class

```
package springmvc_test.user

public class User {
    private String username;
    private String password;
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }
    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

and controller class as the flowing

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = {"/user"} )
public class UserController {
    private List<User> users;

    @Autowired
    public UserController(List<User> users) {
        this.users = users;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/add",method = POST)
    public String addUser(User user,Model m){
        users.add(user);
        //do some other stuf
        //.....
    }

}
```

when i do post-request for `http://localhost/myapp/user/add` 
along with form fields that has the same names as `User` class properties,
it works fine.

but my question is that
how could springmvc find the `User` class and instantiated it ?although the `User` class is not annotated with noting at all

note:
i know that spring binds the `User` object properties by matching their names with form fields names

Comment: Don't you missing `@ModelAttribute` annotation on `user` parameter as described in this link https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-form-tutorial ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the [Spring Framework reference states in the respective section](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.1.5.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-methods) you should use either:

- [`@RequestBody`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.1.5.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-requestbody), if you want to let a `HttpMessageConverter` deserialize your HTTP request to any Java `Object`
- [`@ModelAttribute`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.1.5.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-modelattrib-method-args) if you want to get access to model variables, e.g. also out of your HTTP request.

on the parameter which you want to associate with your request data.